# How to tune hierarchical k-means tree for better performance or accuracy

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, k-means

I want to use OpenCV/FLANN implementation of hierarchical k-means tree. There is 4 parameters available to tune:

```
struct KMeansIndexParams : public IndexParams
{
    KMeansIndexParams(
        int branching = 32,
        int iterations = 11,
        flann_centers_init_t centers_init = CENTERS_RANDOM,
        float cb_index = 0.2 );
};
```

How to choose values of this parameters to balance between performance and accuracy?

Comment: You should try different parameters on _your_ data...

Comment: What are good ranges for these parameters? Are there any rules, like if you increase branching parameter, it will work slower but may produce better accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is one of the things that hugely depend on your data. There are no ranges that would suit all cases. Slow does not necessarily mean better performance. Therefore, your only option would be to experiment different settings with your data and try to reach your target performance.